# How do I revert back to cloud firestore after running firebase emulator suite

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I successfully installed and ran the firestore emulator but I now want to revert back to cloud firestore.
I thought if I would just remove FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings then it would revert to default. I have tried FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings =Settings() to set it back to default but its not working. Please help.

My code before running emulator

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
// import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import './routes_theme.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(Tapp());
}

class Tapp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  

// Set the host as soon as possible.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('error');
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
       
        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return RoutesAndTheme();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

my code after I ran emulator:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import './routes_theme.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(Tapp());
}

class Tapp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  final String host = defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
      ? '10.0.2.2:8080'
      : 'localhost:8080';

// Set the host as soon as possible.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('error');
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings =
            Settings(host: host, sslEnabled: false);
        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return RoutesAndTheme();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: jsut run the command     $firebase deploy      and see if that works

Comment: It doesn't work. the command results in a  error: "cannot understand which targets to deploy"

Comment: did you run the command form the project dir?

Comment: Yes, the same dir from where I ran firebase emulators: start

Comment: I just want to know how to reconnect to cloud firestore

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" does it show any errors?

Comment: After setting the FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings once, I was unable to access the CF project I had initially. By not working I mean that I am unable to access my CF database. I solved the issue by creating a new project in Firebase and then adding the new google services file to my app. I now feel that the problem lies with the emulator project that was created. the firebase.json file may be overriding the settings of my app. If anyone is aware of how to properly switch between emulator and CF, I would really appreciate a step by step guide. thank you!